# Custom Keyboard Name without "KeyboardName - HostAppName" scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, custom-keyboard

I have small problem, I have changed `Bundle Display Name` in `info.plist` to **"MyName"**, but unfortunately in Keyboard Choice Menu it still shows as **"MyName — HostAppName"**. Is that possible to change something to show **"MyName"** only?

Thanks in advance! And yes I have searched through entire STO to find anything about that :)

Comment: ya it is possible, you need to  change the extension Name

Comment: I did change Extension Name in it's info.plist and nothing changes though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I too was wondering how to achieve this, especially after Swiftkey was able to have a single name. To do this **both the Bundle display name in both info.plist files must be the same.**

The moment they are different then they will display with separated string.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by setting "**Bundle Display Name**" key with value "**My Name**" in both info.plist files

1. info.plist file in your keyboard target
2. info.plist file of you Application

Comment: This does not do the trick, because the name still of target is showed in **"MyName — HostAppName"** style

Comment: did you change "Bundle Display Name" in the containing app info.plist file to "**My Name**" ??